# rearrange grouped data and legends in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data set:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:9, 
                 y = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b",3), rep("c", 3)),
                 z = rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3"), 3))
```

I plotted it as barplots grouped by column y:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=y, y=x, fill=z)) +
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
```

The legend is organized as g1, g2, and g3.

Is it posible to re-arrange the graph so the order in each group is g2, g1, g3?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `factor` to specify the order of the levels before plotting.

```
df$z <- factor(df$z, levels = c("g2", "g1", "g3"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = y, y = x, fill = z)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]